# trying to set up a Route 53 zone. What do i use for the A record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-route53

got a technical question I hope you guys can help me with. I'm trying to set up a Route 53 zone. For the A record, do I use the EC2 instance's private IP or the elastic IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic IP, If you want publicity for your server